# DSpace RecentSiteSubmissions returns 0 items while RecentCommunitySubmissions Collection works fine

Tags: java, jsp, solr, dspace

I am upgrading one of my client's DSpace from version 4.1 to 6.2 using the following guide: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Upgrading+DSpace.
Everything works fine except that the RecentSiteSubmissions seems to not return any items causing it to not show the recent submissions carousel on the home page.

The weird thing is RecentCommunitySubmissions and RecentCollectionSubmissions works fine and the carousel is showing on respective page.

Here is relevant configuration in the local.cfg:

```
recent.submissions.count = 20
webui.collectionhome.browse-name = title
webui.collectionhome.perpage = 20
webui.collectionhome.use.dateaccessioned = true

plugin.sequence.org.dspace.plugin.CommunityHomeProcessor = \
        org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentCommunitySubmissions,\
        org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.SideBarFacetProcessor

plugin.sequence.org.dspace.plugin.CollectionHomeProcessor = \
        org.dspace.app.webui.components.CollectionItemList,\
        org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.SideBarFacetProcessor,\
        org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentCollectionSubmissions

plugin.sequence.org.dspace.plugin.SiteHomeProcessor = \
        org.dspace.app.webui.components.TopCommunitiesSiteProcessor,\
        org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentSiteSubmissions,\
        org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.SideBarFacetProcessor
```

I've done some debugging and make sure that `(RecentSubmissions)request.getAttribute("recent.submissions")`  in home.jsp is not null, but the `count()` is evaluated to 0.

I have no clue where to look anymore. Can you guys please give me some hints where to look for? What am I doing wrong? Or if you guys need more information, please guide me on how can I get it?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

What I've just found out is that it seems the query to solr does not contains any filter at all so it returns 0 rows. But I have no idea why.

```
2018-07-12 16:01:40,541 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:01:40,653 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:01:48,706 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:01:55,236 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:01:57,502 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
2018-07-12 16:01:58,235 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:01:58,996 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
2018-07-12 16:01:59,606 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:02:00,146 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=0
2018-07-12 16:02:00,744 INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore @ [search] webapp=/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&version=2} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you rebuilt your discovery index (using .../dspace/bin/dspace index-discovery) since you upgraded?  I wonder if the site level discovery object needs to be re-generated.

Documentation for the command is here: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Discovery

`index-discovery -b` will force a rebuild of your entire index. Depending on the size of your repository, this could take some time to complete.

Comment: Yes I've rebuild the index, but the issue still persist. I apologize for not putting this information in the question earlier.